# Discord.py suggestion command that dm's user id/ bot devs

Tags: python, discord.py

So I wanted to make a suggestion command that send's a direct message to the bot owner like
?suggestion Add 8ball command
and the bot would react to that message and dm the bot owner that suggestion

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: [What have you done?](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beatles/sexysadie.html)

Comment: I tried using this @bot.command()
async def suggest(msg,*,user_suggestion):
    file=open(r"E:\Test12\Testing\hello.json",'r')
    data=json.load(file)
    data.append(user_suggestion)
    with open(r"E:\Test12\Testing\hello.json",'w')as f:
        f.write(str(json.dumps(data)))
        f.close()
    await msg.message.add_reaction(emoji='\U00002705')
But I got an error with data=json.load(file)

Comment: @enzo The heck did you just add as a link? xD

Comment: @Nenz You can update your answer and that those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To react to a message, use

```
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

as defined [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction).

For a bot to send a DM, you will need to create or retrieve the required `channel` object.

```
userForDM = client.get_user(userID)
if userForDM.dm_channel is None:
    await userForDM.create_dm()
await userForDM.dm_channel.send(content)
```

---

Guessing that you're using the `on_message()` event, it would be something like

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # your code

    # if command is suggestion:
    await message.add_reaction("")

    userForDM = client.get_user(123456789)
    if userForDM.dm_channel is None:
        await userForDM.create_dm()
    await userForDM.dm_channel.send(message.content)
```

Where `123456789` obviously has to be replaced with your user ID.

Comment: Users are already Messageables, so you can just invoke [`User.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#id7) and avoid handling the DM channel manually. As well, [`get_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) takes an integer, not a string.